# C# Interface Type Convertion on Implements

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I want to cast the type of the interface definition in the C# implementation.

ex):

```
public interface IModel
{
    IModel Apply(IModel from);
}

public class XxxModel: IModel
{
    public XxxModel Apply(XxxModel from)  // <- Interface Implementation Error
    {
    }
}
```

As a Countermeasure:

```
public class XxxModel: IModel
{
    public IModel Apply(IModel from)
    {
        if (from.GetType() != typeof(XxxModel))
            throw new ArgumentException("Type Not Matched.");
        ...
    }
}
```

However, this leaves open the possibility of errors during execution.
I want to make the types of the argument and return value an implementation class.

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a generic interface, using the implementation class for its generic type:

```
public interface IModel<T> where T: IModel<T>
{
    T Apply(T from);
}

public class XxxModel: IModel<XxxModel>
{
    public XxxModel Apply(XxxModel from)  // All good
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sinatr, John Alexiou!!

Comment: It worked properly.
I didn't expect it to work in seconds!

Comment: Think of `T` as the _derived_ type. `T` is whatever type implements the interface.